# How to find IDs that do not have data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I am trying to write a query that will pull up IDs that do not have certain data in their table.  Currently, we are trying to find people that belong in a certain table but are missing data.

For example, we want to make sure everyone has all three of these items

## Table1

item_ID

- item_1
- item_2
- item_3

And we have this below table

## Table2

ID .. item_ID

- 1 .. item_1
- 1 .. item_2
- 1 .. item_3
- 2 .. item_1
- 2 .. item_2
- 3 .. item_1

And so on.  You can see that ID 2 is missing item_3 from their table, and I want to pull a tuple that displays 2, item_3 in a query.

So far, I have something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.ID, a.item
    FROM TABLE1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 b
            ON a.ITEM_ID=b.ITEM_ID
WHERE b.ITEM_ID is NULL
```

I've been trying to write something where I can pull the item_IDs some IDs are missing, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Does table2.ID reference another table?

Comment: If i understand well, you trying to retrieve data from table 1, where item IDs are missing in table 2 and associate each one to the right ID in the table 2. Maybe i need more infos, but finding missing item IDs in table 2 is pretty easy, but i c'ant figure how you can associate missing item IDs with the right id in table 2 after. How you will know item 3 is related to id 2 in table 2 as exemple ?  To make a query, you must first be able to answer this question.

Comment: Hi. What does "not have certain data in their table" mean? When is it the case that an id has some data "missing"? When it doesn't have a row with a value that is in table 1? You do not clearly explain what you want & you don't show an example of input with desired output. You just give a *wrong* query. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, b.item_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table2) AS a 
-- or TableX AS a -- if you have a TableX with the unique ID values used for Table2 
CROSS JOIN Table1 AS b
-- or (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM Table2) AS b -- if Table1 was not available
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS c ON a.ID = c.ID AND b.item_id = c.item_id
WHERE c.ID IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Would it not be b.item_id instead of a.item_id on line 6?

Comment: @MatthewI Please consider clicking on the check mark icon to "accept" this answer to show it is the most helpful. Both you & the answerer also get reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full list of IDs in table2 then you can use that but if you don't, you can use this:

```
SELECT ft.* 
FROM TABLE2 t2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT b.ID, a.ITEM_ID
  FROM TABLE1 a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE2) b) ft
      ON t2.id = ft.id AND t2.item_id = ft.item_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0a19/7

I do a `CROSS JOIN` to get a list of what all the possible combinations should be and then choose the missing ones from the table.

Comment: The OP might want to take note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN - the alternative generally being considered easier for humans to comprehend: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0a19/8